# Ambiguity regarding got/gotten usage (in AmE)

Tags: american-english, have-got, got-gotten

I am aware of the way to use got/gotten in BrE vs AmE. 
I have come across a phrase which, to my eyes at least, seems one where both can be used (we're talking about AmE now).

*He opened his drawer and removed two items. He then came closer and showed me what he'd **gotten***

Now, following the rule stating that *gotten* is used when indicating that the subject had acquired/obtained something, the phrase above is obviously correct. But, I was thinking, since we are talking about two items that (in the context) actually belonged to that person (as in, they were in his drawer), would not the form *showed me what he'd got* also be acceptable?

Note:
This question has been marked as a duplicate. It's not, I understand the differences mentioned in the other article. I'm asking about **ambiguity** - i.e. cases (such as this particular example) where both as possible. Let me try to rephrase the question:

Is it possible to make a subtle difference in meaning as follows?

1) *He showed me what he'd got* (he showed me the items he had in his drawer)

2) *He showed me what he'd gotten* (he showed me the items he obtained from his drawer)

Comment: 'He was wearing a baseball cap' is acceptable. But it means something different again. I don't know how rigorously the two constructions (using _got_ and _gotten_) **are** differentiated in US usage (ie whether they always have the obtain vs possess distinction), but why should either not be available?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please refer to my added clarification.

Comment: Yes, they're both acceptable. And to me, there's a clear difference in meaning, even if it's not a very big difference.

Answer (score 1):

> He opened his drawer and removed two items. He then came closer and showed me what he'd gotten.

To me (AmE speaker), this means "he showed me what he'd gotten out of the drawer," i.e. what he'd removed from the drawer.

I would not say "got" in this sentence.  I only say "got" for things like "I've got rhythm" (= I have rhythm) and "I got it!" (= I caught the ball, I found the solution to a puzzle).  When I need a past participle, I say "gotten".